# Realtek Wifi connection drops after couple of minutes or hours on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, realtek

Did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 like 2 weeks ago on my machine and since a couple of days the wifi connection breaks all of a sudden after a couple of minutes / sometimes hours. Wifi adapter is down. Could this be a driver issue? Ethernet works fine.

I'm using `driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-45-generic`, `RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter`

```
   $ ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
inet 192.168.0.200/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
   valid_lft 3580sec preferred_lft 3580sec
inet6 fe80::a820:bdf9:daac:9461/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'wlp6s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'vmnet1' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
inet 172.16.1.1/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global vmnet1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::<IP6 'vmnet1' [IF3]>/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'vmnet8' [IF4]> brd <MAC address>
inet 192.168.88.1/24 brd 192.168.88.255 scope global vmnet8
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::<IP6 'vmnet8' [IF4]>/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


   $ dmesg | tail
[  120.033618] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  122.336826] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  122.336838] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: mac power on failed
[  122.336839] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  122.336840] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: leave idle state failed
[  122.336992] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[  122.336994] rtw_pci 0000:06:00.0: failed to leave idle state
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be less of an answer and more of an experiment. Please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtw88 lps_deep_mode=0"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtw88.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

I suspect that the cause of the drops and failure to properly recover is caused by imperfect implementation of power saving deep sleep.

Reference: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11146427/

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11146433/

Comment: Power management seems indeed to be the problem. Following the suggestion on another forum I disabled the power management and since then I did not have the problem anymore. 
``sudo sed -i "s/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/g" /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf``